# How to make the promise return results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have a requirement where we need to write a node module using promises. So there would be 3 different promises. Result should be sent back only when all three of them resolve. I have written some code. Currently the result comes as undefined. Let me know what can I add to fix this.

This is the node module code -

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getData = function() {
    var Q = require('q');

    var result = 0;

    // Promise 1
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var promise1 = Q.fcall(function() {
      setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi');deferred.resolve(9);}, 1000 );
      return deferred.promise;
    });


    promise1.then(function(contents) {
        result = result + contents;
      console.log(contents);
    });

    // promise 2

    var deferred2 = Q.defer();

    var promise2 = Q.fcall(function() {
      setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi');deferred2.resolve(10);}, 1000 );
      return deferred2.promise;
    });


    promise2.then(function(contents) {
        result = result + contents;
      console.log(contents);
    });

    // promise3

    var deferred3 = Q.defer();

    var promise3 = Q.fcall(function() {
      setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi');deferred3.resolve(11);}, 1000 );
      return deferred3.promise;
    });


    promise3.then(function(contents) {
        result = result + contents;
      console.log(contents);
    });

};
```

This is the invoking code -

```
var x = require('./example5.js');

var result = x.getData();

console.log(' Result is ' + result);
```

So I need to figure out a way to hold on to the execution of the node module until all the promises are resolved.

Currently the output is -

Result is undefined

P.S I am a newbie to node.js. So if this is something very obvious, please excuse me!

I think the question was flagged as duplicate. However in the other question, I could not find solution to return the result back. It still returns the promise.

Comment: If the promises are indepentent of each other, Promise.all should do the trick. Otherwise research [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to deal with the nesting hell that you might run into when having too much then-ables.

Comment: Will await work with q promise library ?

Comment: I checked the other question. It does not mention how to return the final result back. The requirement is not to return the promise back.

Comment: @user3276247 It does though. It's an asynchronous operation so you need to handle getting the final result via the `.then` function.

Comment: @MikeC, Actually the requirement is that we host the service and external clients can access this service as a REST service. Now to this client, we need to return data and not the promise. So I need to figure out a way to return the final data back.

Comment: @user3276247 They have to respond to the Promise. Either using `then` or `await`. There is literally no other way. The Promise is an asynchronous process carrying the data you need. You absolutely, positively cannot access asynchronous data from a synchronous process. It's like asking someone to make you a burger then running by the grill with your arm out. The burger is not going to be ready. You have to wait for them to tell you it's done.

Comment: @user3276247 If it's a REST service and you're writing the server side of it, don't send a response back to the user until you've gotten your data back. If you're writing the client-side which is consuming the service, they have to wait for a callback to their (presumably) AJAX call like normal.

Comment: @MikeC The idea is to write the server code in node.js. That is why we are trying to explore as to how not to send a response back to the user until the data is available from the services.

Comment: @user3276247 Then you've taken the right step with writing it with promises. If you're using express then just have to do, if I remember correctly, `promise.then(data => res.send(data))` give or take some for manipulating your data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all()`, to get "a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

Comment: Promise.all still returns a promise back. I need to return the final result.

Comment: Use the value passed in to `then`.